# How to exclude one particular field from a collection in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a NodeJS application with Mongoose ODM(**Mongoose 3.3.1**). I want to retrieve all fields except 1 from my collection.For Example: I have a collection Product Which have 6 fields,I want to select all except a field "Image" . I used "**exclude**" method, but got error..
This was my code.

```
    var Query = models.Product.find();
    Query.exclude('title Image');

    if (req.params.id) {
        Query.where('_id', req.params.id);
    }


    Query.exec(function (err, product) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.send({ 'statusCode': 200, 'statusText': 'OK', 'data': product });
        } else {
            return res.send(500);
        }
    });
```

But this returns **error**

```
Express
500 TypeError: Object #<Query> has no method 'exclude'.........
```

Also I tried, `var Query = models.Product.find().exclude('title','Image');` and `var Query = models.Product.find({}).exclude('title','Image');`  But getting the same error. How to exclude one/(two) particular fields from a collection in Mongoose.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Use [`query.select`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) for field selection in the current (3.x) Mongoose builds.

Prefix a field name you want to exclude with a `-`; so in your case:

```js
Query.select('-Image');
```

Quick aside: in JavaScript, variables starting with a capital letter should be reserved for constructor functions.  So consider renaming `Query` as `query` in your code.

Comment: You can also exclude sub doc fields by doing: `-Image.width`

Comment: consider that image is an array of object, on finding data I need image array data excluding one field value. then what should I do?

Answer (score 50):

I don't know where you read about that .exclude function, because I can't find it in any documentation.

But you can exclude fields by using the second parameter of the find method.

Here is an example from [the official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/):

```
db.inventory.find( { type: 'food' }, { type:0 } )
```

> This operation returns all documents where the value of the type field is food, but does not include the type field in the output.

Comment: I read about **exclude** in [http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/query.html]. As in the answer above my **Image** field can have different values for different product(each row)

Comment: He's asking about mongoose, you're using the native driver.

Comment: saved my life.. delete user.password wasn't consistently working.. was afraid to go live that way

Answer (score 38):

```
Model.findOne({ _id: Your Id}, { password: 0, name: 0 }, function(err, user){
  // put your code
});
```

this code worked in my project. Thanks!! have a nice day.

Answer (score 23):

You could do this

```
const products = await Product.find().select(['-image'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
const products = await Product.find().select({
  "image": 0
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can exclude the field from the schema definition
by adding the attribute

```
    excludedField : {
...
    select: false,
...
    }
```

whenever you want to add it to your result,
add this to your find()

```
find().select('+excludedFiled')
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I am use this with async await

```
async (req, res) => {
      try { 
        await User.findById(req.user,'name email',(err, user) => {
          if(err || !user){
            return res.status(404)
          } else {
            return res.status(200).json({
              user,
            });
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the updated version of Mongoose you can use it in this way as below to get selected fields.

```
user.findById({_id: req.body.id}, 'username phno address').then(response => {
  res.status(200).json({
    result: true,
    details: response
  });
}).catch(err => {
  res.status(500).json({ result: false });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a feature. I store a userId array name "collectedUser" than who is collected the project. And I just want to return a field "isCollected" instead of "collectedUsers". So select is not what I want. But I got this solution.

This is after I get projects from database, I add "isCollected".

```
for (const item of projects) {
    item.set("isCollected", item.collectedUsers.includes(userId), {
        strict: false,
    })
}
```

And this is in Decorator @Schema

```
@Schema({
timestamps: true,
toObject: {
    virtuals: true,
    versionKey: false,
    transform: (doc, ret, options): Partial<Project> => {
        return {
            ...ret,
            projectManagers: undefined,
            projectMembers: undefined,
            collectedUsers: undefined
        }
    }
}
})
```

Finally in my controller

```
projects = projects.map(i => i.toObject())
```

It's a strange tricks that set undefined, but it really work.

Btw I'm using nestjs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a way to always omit a field - more like a global option rather than doing so in the query e.g. a password field, using a getter that returns undefined also works

```js
{
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      get: () => undefined,
    },
}
```

NB: Getters must be enabled with option `{ toObject: { getters:true } }`