# Mongoose returns "new ObjectId" in _id field of the result

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

When I try to query, the result contains the `_id` field with "new ObjectId()" in it. How to avoid this "new ObjectId()" and only include the hash value as string. Because of this issue, sending the data back as JSON response is failing.

The following is a basic demo:

**My code for querying:**

```
book_data = await Book.find({ slug: 'test' }).
                        where('status').equals('Active').select('title').exec()

console.log( book_data )
```

**Response:**

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6164aff742da0eac31a87b9a"),
    title: 'Test' 
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in an options object to the `.find` method. There, you can specify the field you want to ignore by providing a 0 as the value.

[See here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14559323/10431732) info as well.

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
book_data = await Book.find(
    { slug: 'test' }, // Query
    { _id: 0 }        // Options
).where('status').equals('Active').select('title').exec();
```

While the above query *should* do the trick, I believe this means you could also just do:

```js
book_data = await Book.find(
    // Query
    { slug: 'test', status: 'Active' },
    // Options
    { _id: 0, title: 1 }                
).exec();
```

### Edit 2

I found a better way to do this via `.find`..

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v9iK2iIsyem)

This is what your code would look like:

```js
book_data = await Book.find({
  slug: "test",
  status: "active"
},
{
  title: 1,
  _id: {
    "$toString": "$_id"
  }
}).exec();
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a handy thing. But I would like to get the value `6164aff742da0eac31a87b9a` instead of `new ObjectId("6164aff742da0eac31a87b9a")`. Is there any way for that?

Comment: Sorry about that @VppMan - please see my update.

Comment: Sorry (again) @VppMan lol - please see `Edit 2` in my answer. I found a better way via `.find`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do to have the string

```
_id.toHexString();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue
Trying to retrieve id (typeof string) from a user object (user._id)on mongoDb;

it was returning a new ObjectId, But .toHexString() solved my problem.
Check out my code snippet below.

```js
const userId = user._id;
console.log(userId) // new ObjectId("64746fa164f0448189eb6c8f")

const userId = user._id.toHexString(),
console.log(userId) // "64746fa164f0448189eb6c8f"
```