# Mongoose populate() returns the '_id' field of populated documents with "new ObjectId()"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

So I'm trying to fetch a set of company member documents that correspond to a specific user, and populate the company field of each document in the process. The aim here is to get the **_id** and the **name** fields of each company document that corresponds to a company member. I've been successful in fetching the company member documents, **however**, the **_id** field of each populated company is **returned together with the "new ObjectId()" constructor** as shown below:

```
The company members:  [
  {
    company: { _id: new ObjectId("6296180fj2a538be87f058f"), name: 'aaa' }
  }
]
```

Of course, the desired outcome is to **get only the _id content without the ObjectId() constructor**. I've tried using the **method suggested in the accepted answer of [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532987/mongoose-returns-new-objectid-in-id-field-of-the-result), however, I got the same results** (meaning the ObjectId() constructor didn't go away):

```
// Fetch up to 10 company members and populate their companies.
let companyMembers = await CompanyMember.find({user: user_id}, {_id: 0, company: 1}).populate({
   path: 'company',
   match: { name: { $regex : new RegExp(company_name, "i") } },
   select: { _id: {"$toString": "$_id"}, name: 1 }
}).limit(10).exec();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `lean()` funtion ?

Comment: For anyone wondering where to put the .lean() function, you have to chain it to the find() function like so: `await Model.find().lean().populate(...).exec();`